# How to identify invalid records from a dimension table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample data. Its a slowing changing dimension (type 2).

| iddim | idperson | name | role | IsActive | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | jim | driver | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | 1234 | jim | driver | 0 | 2022-02-03 | 9999-12-31 |
| 3 | 3456 | tom | accountant | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-08-30 |
| 4 | 4567 | patty | assistant | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |

Due to a server error one of my ssis packages performed some unexpected actions and there are now `idperson` without the 99991231 end date (ie. Tom)

I require to identify them so I can manually modify this condition so my resulting table will be

| iddim | idperson | name | role | IsActive | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | jim | driver | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | 1234 | jim | driver | 0 | 2022-02-04 | 9999-12-31 |
| 3 | 3456 | tom | accountant | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-08-30 |
| 4 | 4567 | patty | assistant | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| 5 | 3456 | tom | accountant | 0 | 2022-08-31 | 9999-12-31 |

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to just update his end date if he wasn't supposed to be termed?  Why would he be IsActive 0 if he is current.  And when you have end and start dates they shouldn't overlap unless you have timestamps that allow them not to overlap.  For instance END 2022-08-30 and Start Should be the following day, unless timestamps are applied when building type two dimensions.

Comment: Just fixed the overlapping dates typo. Regarding your fist question, my table logic requires all personnel to have one record with a endDate 9999-12-31 as this is considered the most recent and valid record. This is part of the slow changing logic type 2 that we implemented

Comment: What criteria distinguishes tom (id=3456) from jim (id=1234) who I presume to be different from the other jim (id=2345)?

Comment: But Jim Driver for instance has an active flag of 0 with his high end date records.  That should be IsActive = 1 not 0.  Your second record would be the active record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand your requirements, you need to generate records to fill the gaps between the latest end date (per person) and '9999-12-31'. the filler records should have IsActive = 0 and should inherit the latest prior name and role for that idperson.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
SELECT
  idperson,
  name,
  role,
  IsActive = 0,
  start = DATEADD(day, 1, [end]),
  [end] = '9999-12-31'
FROM (
  SELECT *, Recency = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idperson ORDER BY [End] DESC)
  FROM @Data
) D
WHERE Recency = 1 AND [end] < '9999-12-31'
ORDER BY iddim
```

The `Recency` value calculated above will be 1 for the latest record per idperson ands 2, 3, etc. for records with older end dates. If the latest record isn't end-of-time, a filler record is generated.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xGvhJnDx) for a working example (which includes a few additional test data records).

Note: The two existing jim records in your original posted data have different idperson values, so they are treated as different persons and the first triggers a gap record.

UPDATE: The above was revised to allow for possible name change over time for a given idperson.